# Automatically increment INT value for specific record after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a MS Access application with SQL Server Express as backend.

I have these tables for Orders and Order Details:

| OrderID | CustomerID | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10.10.2023 |
| 2 | 1 | 11.10.2023 |

| OrderDetailID | OrderID | ItemOrder | ProductName | Quantity | UnitPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Product A | 5 | 500 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | Product B | 3 | 120 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | Product C | 1 | 1000 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | Product A | 8 | 500 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | Product D | 4 | 10 |

Every Order Detail has a unique ItemOrder specified, **WITHIN A PARTICULAR ORDER**.

So for example:

- if I added a new Item to OrderID=1, its ItemOrder would be 4
- if I added a new Item to OrderID=2, its ItemOrder would be 3
- if I created a new Order=3 and added its first Item, its ItemOrder would be 1

I'm looking for a way to automate this. Currently I do it on the VBA side in MS Access, like this:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
     Me.ItemOrder = Nz(DMax("ItemOrder", "tblOrders", "OrderID=" & Me.Parent.OrderID), 0) + 1
End Sub
```

Then I have some VBA functions to rearrange order of the items, but that is not relevant for my question.

The problem comes when SQL server wants to insert data, and sometimes more records at the same time. Is there a good way to do this on the SQL server side, perhaps using AFTER INSERT triggers? What about bulk inserts?

Comment: Don't automate it. Instead just use an `IDENTITY`/`SEQUENCE` and create a `VIEW` the determines these values using `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: I need to physically store the order, so I am able to rearrange the items.

Comment: Why do you *need* to store it? This is smelling like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: So I can rearrange the items. For example show a particular item first in the order confirmation.

Comment: You don't need to nor should you store it, you can already infer it given the order defined by the primary key

Comment: If you need a different order, use a different `ORDER BY`.

Comment: OK, maybe I should explain this in a more simple way. I want to be able to display the items in a completely custom order as I see fit, and be able to change this order. For example when an order has 3 items and I decide that after all, I want to display the third item as first. Not sure how Primary Key or ORDER BY would help me, without physically storing the item order value.

Comment: Sounds like that's an application task, not a SQL task.

Comment: Yes, currently I deal with it in the application, but my question was if this can be achieved on the SQL server, like written above.

Comment: If your application controls the order, sql server cannot do anything to create it. So keep using that VBA

Comment: SQL can only change the order of the result by use of the `order by` clause, so unless you have some field(s) you can order by on SQL cannot do this. An application has a bit more freedom to play with a result set, that is why this is normally done in the application

Comment: I don't think you gain anything to setting these values in the database, stick to doing it in code as you are. What benefit were you hoping for?